# Generic FlatFileItemWritter Insert Separate Values In Different Rows Instead Of One

Tags: java, csv, spring-batch

Im using a generic FlatFileItemWritter to create a csv, but when i create it , all the values are inserted in one column

here is my FlatFileItemWritter XML:

```
<bean id="flatFileItemWriter"
          class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter"
          scope="step">

        <property name="resource"
                  value="file:${folder.destination}" />

        <property name="lineAggregator">

            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">

                <property name="delimiter" value="," />

                <property name="fieldExtractor">

                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                        <property name="names"
                                  value="${sql.fields}" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

To sum up the data are saved like this in the Csv:

```
Column 1                    | Column 2 | Column 3 |
Christian,9999999-A,Company |          |          |
```

The column 1, column2 and column 3 are only an example of how it is stored in the CSV, i dont want a `header`

I want to store the data like this in different columns not all in the first:

```
Christian,9999999-A,Company
```

I get the values sql.fields and folder.destination througth a properties

Is possible to do what i want whit the generic FlatFileItemWritter or i need to do a customFlatFileItemWritter

If you need more things to see i will edit this

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for read me

Answer (score -1):

Maybe i'm late on this, but if you want the header and the datas, maybe you should write something to do the header separately ? 
 
setHeaderCallback should do the trick :

[http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemWriter...](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemWriter.html#setHeaderCallback-org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileHeaderCallback-) 
 
If the problem persist, the properties used would be helpful.

Comment: I provably put a bad example i edited my question for better explained

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Just, i wonder, the delimiter you are using is ",", so it's kind of normal to have all in one column. Just use the excel properties : **Data tab**, in the **Data Tools** group and **Text to Columns**. That's (for all I know) the only way.